# Testing RUBY_PLATFORM with RSpec 2

Tags: ruby, testing, environment-variables, tdd, rspec2

Is there a way to change the `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant so that I can test the following method?

```ruby
def determine_os
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
    when /darwin/ then :mac
    when /linux/ then :linux
    else raise InvalidOSError
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RUBY_PLATFORM` shouldn't be used to determine operating system. Use the appropriate item within the hash `RbConfig` instead.

Also, if you want to make it more easily tested, you could do

```
def determine_os(os_string)
  case os_string
    when /darwin/ then :mac
    when /linux/ then :linux
    else raise InvalidOSError
  end
end
```

and you could do `determine_os("darwin")` for your test.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewGrimm! `RbConfig['host_os']` does seem to be the best way to access this information. I also found that the change to `#determine_os` you suggested made testing much easier. I've adjusted a few other methods in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it. (will generate warnings, ignore them)

```
RUBY_PLATFORM = "darwin"
determine_os              #=> :mac
RUBY_PLATFORM = "mingw"
determine_os              #=> raises InvalidOSError
```

Comment: Haha. Thanks. That is the first thing I tried, but there was another problem with my test, which I assumed was related to the warnings.